# How to establish a connection which will be used to sending data by server to application?

Tags: android, networking

I am preparing an application for Android which will display current status of some services.

Application should get this information from my server. However there is no rule in periods between changes of statuses.

I want to avoid unnecessary requests to server.

How to establish a kind of connection, which will allow server to decide when send delta to application?

Comment: go for C2DM or use pulling ... keeping opened connection will drain battery edit: or use both ... C2DM for inform device that should refresh service status

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Push notification technique will be good for your case

Refrences;

- [Android C2DM](http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/)
- http://tokudu.com/2010/how-to-implement-push-notifications-for-android/
- http://blog.boxedice.com/2010/10/07/android-push-notifications-tutorial/
- http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidCloudToDeviceMessaging/article.html

Answer (score 1):

Use the [c2dm](http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/) framework. They even have a sample application for Android and AppEngine: [Jumpnote](http://code.google.com/p/jumpnote/)